# as3 writing bits to ByteArray object using writeByte method

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a string of bits(binary number) and I want to write it to a ByteArray(or maybe later in a file) is it correct to do it this way or should I first convert the binary string to hex ?

```
var bits:String="11001110";//8 bits a byte
var CompressedBytes = new ByteArray();
CompressedBytes.writeByte((int)(bits));
```

and if so please provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is **almost** correct. Use the global **[parseInt(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseInt())** function that reads a given **String** and converts it into a **Number**. There's an optional second argument that allows you to specify a base of the number you are willing to parse. The most common values are 2 (for binary notation), 8 (for octal numbers), 10 (for decimal numbers, which is **default**) or 16 (for hexadecimal notation).

```
var bits:String = "11001110"; //8 bits a byte
var aByte:int = parseInt(bits, 2);

var CompressedBytes = new ByteArray;
CompressedBytes.writeByte(aByte);
```

P.S. You can convert a **Number** (also **int** and **uint**) to a **String** notation with a given base via **[toString(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toString())** method.